# modify oracle query start with

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following query written by other developers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id category_id,
  c.parent_id,
  d.name AS category_name,
  level
FROM category c,
  category_language d
WHERE c.id                                 = d.category_id
AND c.is_active                            = 1
AND c.is_deleted                           = 0
AND c.deleted_date                        IS NULL
AND d.is_active                            = 1
AND d.is_deleted                           = 0
AND d.deleted_date                        IS NULL
AND ((to_date(d.expiry_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') > to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY'))
OR d.expiry_date                          IS NULL)
AND d.language_id                          = 1
AND c.cat_type_id                          = 1
  START WITH c.parent_id                   =1308206844
  CONNECT BY c.parent_id                   = prior c.id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY d.name
```

I had two problems.

First, I don't know how **START WITH**, **CONNECT BY**, **PRIOR** Keywords are working in query.

Second, when I change **ORDER SIBLINGS BY d.name** to **ORDER SIBLINGS BY c.priority desc** following error message is thrown:=

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
01791. 00000 -  "not a SELECTed expression"
```

I had also tried to change the Datatype of priority from number to string but same error is thrown.

I want to run query of order by c.priority desc for producing desired results.

Comment: @hol: You are right to say learn with these oracle keywords. By the way, the solution to problem is that i forget to select c.priority on the select statement when i write order by c.priority desc.Now its working fine... :)

Comment: Cool. This is because the result set gets ordered and so you have to include it. Happy my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

The keywords `START WITH, CONNECT BY, PRIOR` are used to display a hierarchy. In my opinion this link is a really good tutorial for it: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html

At least I learned how to use it following the examples. Maybe this also gives you the answer what `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` really means and then you can answer yourself how to avoid the error message. Apparently Oracle wants you to include the column in the selected columns. `ORDER SIBLINGS` is specific to hierarchy and you can google it. But I think you first need to learn about `START WITH, CONNECT BY, PRIOR`

Maybe you do not want to do a `ORDER SIBLINGS BY` but a `ORDER BY` only.